# Will fortran's 'matmul' make use of MKL if I include the library?

Tags: fortran, intel, lapack

I am writing some code right now and I have a placeholder with `matmul` that seems to be working pretty well, but I'd like to use a `LAPACK` `dgemm` implementation. I am only using `gfortran` right now and getting very good speeds with `matmul`, but I wonder if I can get better.

The current call is:

```
C = transpose(matmul( transpose(A), B))
```

where `A`, `B`, and `C` are non-square, `double precision` matrices. I can easily write a wrapper for `dgemm` with the current `gfortran` implementation of `LAPACK`, but I like that I can do this all as a function (rather than worrying about `call` for a surbroutine and having to deal with the `transpose`).

I am wondering if I compile with `ifort` and include the `MKL`, will this `matmul` magically change to a `MKL` `dgemm` function for me with no wrapper?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't want all MATMULs to be dgemm, it is not profitable for very small matrices.

Gfortran does what you want

> -fexternal-blas
>       This option will make gfortran generate calls to BLAS functions for some matrix operations like MATMUL, instead of using our own
>   algorithms, if the size of the matrices involved is larger than a
>   given limit (see -fblas-matmul-limit). This may be profitable if an
>   optimized vendor BLAS library is available. The BLAS library will have
>   to be specified at link time.

and you can even change the size limit for switching to BLAS by -fblas-matmul-limit=n

You can easily use MKL this way in gfortran.

Intel Fortran has something similar

> [no
>   - ] opt-matmul This option enables [disables] a compiler
>   - generated Matrix Multiply (matmul) library call by identifying matrix multiplicat ion loop nests , if any , and replacing them with a
>   matmul library call for improved performance. This option is enabled
>   by default if options / O3 (
>   - O3) and /Qparallel (
>   - parallel) are specified. This option has no effect unless option / O2 (
>   - O2) or higher is set.